# Использование сообщения пользователя в функции. aiogram telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

В моём боте пользователь должен ввести дату рождения, после чего мне нужно взять эту дату, передать в определённую функцию и результат этой функции вставить в качестве индекса в списке, из которого пользователю будет отправлено соответствующее изображение. Демонстрирую часть кода, тут пример и хендлера, и функции, через которую я хочу прогнать сообщение пользователя. Всё работает, если передавать не значение из функции, а просто рандомно сгенерированное число. Но мне нужно именно результат полученный благодаря соответствующим вычислениям, а для этого надо в переменную передать сообщение отправленное пользователем, чтобы с ним можно было дальше работать, и вот именно это у меня сделать не получается. Собственно вопрос: как в aiogram сообщение пользователя присвоить переменной, чтобы дальше с ним взаимодействовать?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def begin(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"{text1}")


@dp.message_handler()
async def datarozh(message: types.Message):
    if message.text[2] == '/' and message.text[5] == '/' and len(message.text) == 10:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Выберите кнопку", reply_markup=mainmenu)

    elif message.text == 'Начало':
        chatid = message.from_user.id
        arkankart = InputFile(path_or_bytesio=f"{img_list[result_def]}") # вот сюда нужно подставить значение из функции после обработки сообщения пользователя
        await dp.bot.send_photo(chat_id=chatid, photo=arkankart, caption='Здесь будет описание')


data = "11/11/2011" # вместо data планируется использовать сообщение пользователя
s = data.split('/')
spisok = []
for i in s:
    spisok.append(int(i))

def day(a): # сама функция, через которую надо прогнать сообщение пользователя, их у меня несколько разных, эта как пример
    result = 0
    while a[0] != 0:
        b = a[0] % 10
        result += b
        a[0] = a[0] // 10
    return result
```

Comment: Ну так просто запустите состояние и получив сообщение от юзера обработайте его, в чем сложность?

Answer (score 0):

Получение текста сообщения производится так: `message.text`. Вот [тут](https://docs.aiogram.dev/ru/latest/api/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message.text) доки.

А вот код, который решает Вашу проблему:

```py
@dp.message_handler(regexp=r'^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}/$')
async def date_handler(msg: Message):
    data: str = msg.text
    some_list = map(int, data.split('/'))
    await msg.answer(day(some_list))


def day(a: list):
    result = 0
    while a[0] != 0:
        b = a[0] % 10
        result += b
        a[0] = a[0] // 10
    return result
```

Заметьте, что используется сопоставление с регулярным выражением, что бы избежать ошибок в случае отправки пользователем неверных данных.

Так же дам Вам пару рекомендаций:

1. Перед тем как идти на StackOverlow, поищите проблему в интернете.
2. Всегда используйте [type-hints](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/), особенно когда публикуете свой код.
3. Сначала выучите Python, а только после этого делайте ботов.